# Can an incorrect (accepted) answer be deleted?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I have found [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/189017/can-you-get-another-boss-soul-by-respawning-bosses-with-a-bonfire-ascetic) about bonfire ascetics in a Dark Souls question, and someone has posted an incorrect answer (it is blatantly incorrect) which has been accepted already.

Can the answer be deleted if it is accepted?

Comment: It's funny how since you posted this Meta post the answer has been downvoted almost four times as much for one day then any other day it's been downvoted

Comment: Well... that's...

Comment: I feel the saying "You can lead a horse to water..." comes into play here somehow...

Comment: "You can lead a horse to water but you can't make it accept it, just down vote it like crazy"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. [This has happened.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/21266/23) This link won't work for non-10kers because, well, it's deleted. But here's the text of the answer:

> [image: In short, you will get Grilled Porkchop. (This is incorrect, the pig will actually turn into a Zombie Pigman)]

If you don't see the problem here, clearly you need to disable images in your browser or view source! Who doesn't do that.

```
![In short, you will get Grilled Porkchop.
  (This is incorrect, the pig will actually turn into a Zombie Pigman)][2]
```

SE is not here to bring answers that look right, we're here to bring answers that *are* right. Sometimes answerers and askers won't be around to keep their answers and their checkmarks up to date. This is especially a problem if the wrong answer is accepted and highly upvoted.

In those exceptional situations, yes, we reserve the right to take exceptional measures.

Comment: So for example, in the question I linked, the same thing has occurred? A user has provided an incorrect answer, that was accepted by the OP.

Comment: @ben I don't know anything about Dark Souls 2 and can't really comment.

Comment: I can verify that the accepted answer is incorrect.

Comment: @Ben I know DS2, and I see how wrong that answer is. Nuked.

Comment: Why not make a flag for this very problem.

Comment: "*clearly you need to disable images in your browser or view source! Who doesn't do that.*" I don't, if i do i potentially miss cute Shoujo Ai/Yuri Images like [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19739388#19739388), [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16399010#16399010) and [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19740717#19740717)

Comment: "This link won't work for non-10kers" Good thing there aren't many of those then...

Answer (score 5):

No. Accepted answers show what worked for the asker, and can't be changed. Votes show the community's opinion, which is sometimes different from the asker's.

I know it is a little frustrating, especially given how much power the community has to change almost any other aspect of a post, but accept votes are protected.

It should be clear to anyone hitting that page that, although it's accepted, the top answer is not correct.

Comment: Sometimes people accept the first answer they see and that _seems_ to work, and then never return even if it didn't actually work.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, accepted answers can be deleted so that the highest-voted answer will be at the top instead. This came up on MSE before.

[Can trusted users delete accepted answers with a negative score?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121282/can-trusted-users-delete-accepted-answers-with-a-negative-score)

The thing is that moderators *technically* aren't supposed to do this to legitimate answers that just happen to be wrong.

Normal users with 20k+ rep can cast delete votes for any reason though.